# making line between 2 text regular

Tags: html, css, class

I have a class which has *login /signup* text. The text font-style is italic. I am wondering how I can make the line (|) between "login" and "sign up" regular but keep the remaining text italic. Also, can we get this by keeping the three things (login, |, Sign Up) in the same class?

At this moment, all three of things (login, |, Sign Up) are italic. The HTML and CSS codes which I have used are:

```css
li.login-signup {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Adelle PE;
  letter-spacing: .30em;
}
```

```html
<li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
```

Comment: Wrap your vertical bar in a span: `<span class="separator">|</span>` - but in most fonts, the vertical bar will still be vertical even when the font-style is *italic* anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest the following:

```css
.login-signup {
  list-style: none;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Adelle PE;
  letter-spacing: .30em;
}

.login-signup li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0.1em 0.8em;
}

.login-signup li:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="login-signup">
    <li>Log In</li>
    <li>Sign up</li>
</ul>
```

- Using two `<li>` elements, as you seem to have two navigational options (even if they happen to do the same at the moment)
- Using CSS (`border-right`) instead of content ("|") for the separator

This improves your markup semantically and gives you more flexibility regarding styling.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do it is:
`<li class="login-signup">Log In <span class="regular">|</span> Sign up</li>`

And then add class .regular {font-style: normal;}